# Get object based on matching key value in nested array

Tags: javascript, json, api, jsonp

I have a movie feed where I'm trying to retrieve the "name" value of an object that has a specific key value. Here's the response:

```
{
    genres: [
        {
            id: 18,
            name: "Drama"
        },
    ],
    homepage: "http://www.therewillbeblood.com/",
    id: 7345,
    imdb_id: "tt0469494",
    release_date: "2007-12-26",
    crew: [
        {
            id: 4762,
            name: "Paul Thomas Anderson",
            department: "Writing",
            job: "Screenplay",
            profile_path: "/6lDE5N6lQUvAbKBRazn2Q0mRk44.jpg"
        },
        {
            id: 52563,
            name: "Upton Sinclair",
            department: "Writing",
            job: "Novel",
            profile_path: null
        },
        {
            id: 2950,
            name: "Robert Elswit",
            department: "Camera",
            job: "Director of Photography",
            profile_path: null
        },
        {
            id: 1809,
            name: "Dylan Tichenor",
            department: "Editing",
            job: "Editor",
            profile_path: null
        },
        {
            id: 4762,
            name: "Paul Thomas Anderson",
            department: "Directing",
            job: "Director",
            profile_path: "/6lDE5N6lQUvAbKBRazn2Q0mRk44.jpg"
        },
        {
            id: 4772,
            name: "Cassandra Kulukundis",
            department: "Production",
            job: "Casting",
            profile_path: null
        }
    ]
}
```

So I'm trying to get the object with the "job" key value of "Director" which would be Paul Thomas Anderson.

And here's my javascript where I'm setting the year variable based on the value of release_date. Just trying to figure out how I can set a director variable:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var url = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/';

imdb_id = 'tt0102685';
key = '?api_key=XXXXXXXXXXXX';
append = '&append_to_response=credits';
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url + imdb_id + key + append,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
      var $year = data.release_date.substring(0, 4);
      $('#year').html($year);
    },
});

});
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Spent almost two days trying to figure it out to no avail.

Answer (score 3):

If your using modern browsers you can use the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function:

```
var name = data.crew.filter(function(e){
    return (e.job=="Director") ? true:false;
})[0].name;
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/gTzyT/

**Example with Error Handling**

```
function getDirectorName(crew){
    var name = "";
    try{
        name = json.crew.filter(function(e){
           return e.job=="Director"
        })[0].name;
    }catch(err){
       name = "No Director";
    }
    return name;    
}

//calling the method                           
alert(getDirectorName(data.crew));
```

Comment: Works, but should probably have error handling code for the case where returned array may be empty.

Comment: Also `(e.job == "Director")` expression already results in a boolean.  No need to use ternary operator to cast to true:false.  So just `return e.job === 'Director';`

Comment: @broofa Care to review the error handling, would like to hear your suggestions.

Comment: Why try-catch instead of a simply checking the returned array length?  I dislike try-catch here for a couple of reasons: 1) it can obscure unexpected errors that calling code may care about, e.g. `e` being undefined and 2) try-catch performance is orders of magnitude worse than `if () ...`.  See http://jsperf.com/try-catch-error-perf/3 ("table" view)

I would also suggest returning null instead of "No Director", as that is (imho) a more semantically correct value.

Answer (score 0):

For a slightly "different" approach, sort by job first.  E.g.

```
data.crew.sort(function(a,b) {
  return a.job == 'Director' ? -1 : 1;
});
console.log(data.crew[0].name); // => name of Director
```

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/pd8ks/)

Note: I'm not necessarily endorsing this solution.  Sorting is not the most performant approach.  And it has side-effects (changes the order of the `data.crew` array, which may not be desirable).  But it's kind of a "cute" solution so I figured I'd toss it out there. :)